# Selenium Web Driver , How to enter text in text in Selenium texbox and hit Enter

Tags: selenium

Once i login to the main application. I want it to enter state name and hit enter function.It is ideally a dropdown but i would like to achieve this by entering text "Colorado" in texbox and hit enter. The text box is located under a dropdown.My question is about how to enter text in Slenium textbox and hit Enter.

The HTML for textbox is as follows,

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-11">
```

My current code is as follows:-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_regionSelect > a > span.select2-arrow")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_autogen1_search")).sendKeys("Colorado");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_autogen1_search"));
            textbox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

It is able to enter text in textbox but does not hit enter. I just need to select the Colorado state and click on different tab.

Comment: can you give URL?

Comment: does the page support the enter key? if you manually access the page and do the same steps then hit the enter key does it behave the way you expect?

Comment: Yes if i manually enter colorado input box and hit enter key it behaves the same way i expect. Someone told me to use Actions class but it didnt work. is there a robot class in java that can perform Enter operation ?

Comment: <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-387" role="option">Colorado</div></li>  So if i want to enter xpath of this i can perform by using actions class and hit enter?

Answer (score 0):

In my C# automation code, I'm using the Actions(OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions) to hit enter in a input field.

`new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Perform();`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to just send a newline character (`\n`) with the text, e.g.

```
driver.findElement(...).sendKeys("Colorado\n");
```

Comment: is this going to press enter after sending Colorado in the text box ?

Comment: It really depends on how the page is set up. I would try it and see if it works for you. It has worked when I have used it in the past.

Comment: This what i have used currently but it didnt work . Shall i update the HTML tag DOM picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use TAB key:

```
WebElement textBox =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_autogen1_search")).sendKeys("Colorado");
textbox.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);// it will change focus to next element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//locate the elements in the page using their properties like``id, name or path etc.

WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));

email.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
```